# android notifications dont appear on its time

Tags: java, android, notifications

hey guys i am working on android application , i am trying to creat a notification for a specific time like ( 03 - august -2012 at 5:00 pm ) , so i used the calender to set the time and then using calendar.getTimeInMillis i get the time of the notification , but unfortunatlly when i run my application on the emulator once the application starts the notification appears without caring about the specfic time, i.e its not 4:00 pm the notification appears on the top and time stamped with 5:00pm , heres my notification code :

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

int icon = R.drawable.ieee;
CharSequence tickerText = "Hello";

//   long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

//setting custom time 
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,03);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,17);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,26);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
long when = calendar.getTimeInMillis();        // notification time

Notification notification=new Notification (icon, tickerText, when);

Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";
CharSequence contentText = "Hello World!";
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

---

now everything is running , but there's a little problem ,,, for example if the date&time now is 9/9/2012 , 9:00 am ,,, and i set the alarm for tomorrow at 10am , okey it will work , but when i open the application the day after tomorrow first thing the app will do is to do notification of the old alarm , i tried this by setting old alarm dates and when i open the app the first thing it does is showing old alarms , so any ideas about solving this ?

Comment: nevermind, cleaning the offset is not the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it will not wait when you haven't told it to. You can't set the `Calendar` time and then expect the notification service to wait.

You need to instead using a `TimerTask` or `AlarmManager` for this to generate an event at the time you want. Then create the notification inside your implementation of either one.

Comment: i guess my error is within this line 
"long when = calendar.getTimeInMillis();        // notification time"

Answer (score 0):

ahaaa , i guess i got your point , or i hope so lol , its like setting the alarm manager on a specific date , so when this date comes the alarm manager sets a flag to certain value "enum i.e" and then within this code segment there will be a checking function which each time it checks this flag if its up then do certain task , right ?
http://androidideasblog.blogspot.com/2011/07/alarmmanager-and-notificationmanager.html
this will helps ALOT !!